# React.js index.js as a class?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to declare index.js as a class? I'm using
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

which index.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';


/*
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
*/

class Apps extends Component {
  ReactDOM.render(
      <div className="App">
        <p> hello </p>
      </div>
  );
}
```

The commented out code is what was before and class Apps is what I want to achieve.

Regards,

Comment: The commented out version is the way to go. You could however write your `App` component in the same file if you would like, but the `ReactDOM.render` is needed as is. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: No. Your top level rendering code has no real reason to be in a class.

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

are the *entry point* of your React app. It says "take all that hierarchy of components composition, render them and mount to a certain node". It's an imperative statement that gets called as soon as code execution reaches this point. This is why you see the app working in your browser.

Putting this instruction into a class declaration would mean: "here's a class that would take all the hierarchy of components...". The problem is, it would never get executed, just as a function declaration doesn't make this function execute.

There is no need to put call to `ReactDOM.render` into any function or class ([which is, again, a function declaration](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=class%20A%20%7B%7D) with nicer syntax). Let it stay in global scope, it's unlikely to cause any trouble at any point.